# ADB Logcat "device unauthorized" when it isn't

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, logcat

I'm using Android Studio and have been experiencing this issue for the last few days (wasn't the case in prior months).

The ADB logs keep giving me this message:

```
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device *********: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
```

I've looked around and tried just about every fix under the sun.. deleting the .android folder to re-accept the dialog box popup for the computer's fingerprint, restarting the ADB server, sacrificing a lamb to the olden gods..

But here's the kicker; if I run it in debug mode, it works as if all was normal. As soon as it hits a breakpoint I can see the Logcat logs, but if I run it in the not-debug (ie. normal?) mode, I get bumped back to the ADB complaint logs. What gives?